# Numpy better ways of iterating over colour channels using binary mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Is there a better way to apply a binary mask to colour channels in numpy? I end up having to do this all the time and it feels like there should be.

```
for c in range(3):
    a_image[mask, c] = b_image[mask, c]
```

shapes are `(x, y, c)` for `a_image` and `b_image`, and `(x, y)` for `mask`.

Comment: `a_image[mask, :] = b_image[mask, :]`?

Comment: Are you sure your code does what you think it does...?

Comment: @DYZ is the colon required?

Comment: @ehsan Not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the 2-D mask on a 3-D array without a loop. Numpy will broadcast it to the third dimension for you.

```
a_image[mask] = b_image[mask]
```

simple example:

```
a_image = np.arange(6).reshape(1,2,3)
#[[[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]]]

b_image = np.ones((1,2,3))
#[[[1. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]]]

mask = np.array([[False,True]])
#[[False  True]]
```

output:

```
[[[0 1 2]
  [1 1 1]]]
```